# smoothing a current

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, schwartz-distributions, smoothing-theory

Let $M$ be a smooth oriented manifold of dimension $n$ and $T$ a current of dimension $k$ on $M$. Let $\phi:P\times M \to M$ be a proper smooth family of diffeomorphisms of $M$ (i.e. $P$ is a smooth manifold, $\phi$ is a smooth proper map, and each $\phi_p:=\phi(p, \cdot)$ is a diffeo of $M$) and $dp$ a smooth measure on $P$. Suppose that $\phi(\cdot,x)$ is a submersion for each $x \in M$.

I claim that the current $S:= \int_P \phi_{p*} T \, dp$ (i.e. $S(\alpha) = \int_P T(\phi_p^*\alpha) \, dp$ for $\alpha$ a $k$-form) is smooth, i.e. is given by integration against a smooth $(n-k)$-form. This should be a standard fact. I think I can give a proof but it is tedious. Does anyone know a reference?

I would be content with a reference covering the case where $T$ is given by integration over a smooth oriented submanifold, but surely this is an artificial restriction.

Comment: If $P$ is a point and $\varphi=\mathrm{Id}_M$, then $S=T$ has no reason to be smooth, or am I missing something?

Comment: Henri--- your example does not satisfy the submersion condition.

Comment: If $M = \mathbb R^n=P $, $P$ acts by translations, and the measure $dp$ is given by the smooth density $f$, then the operation reduces to convolution with $f$. Strictly speaking this example violates the properness condition, but if $f$ has compact support then it is OK (the properness condition can be relaxed to: $\phi$ is proper on $supp (dp) \times M$).

Comment: indeed, I had missed the submersion assumption, my bad!

Comment: I think the result follows from the standard fact that smearing $T(x)$ with some $\rho(x,y)$, which is smooth in both arguments, gives something smooth. This can be made global using a partition of unity subordinate to a cover that is adapted to put the submersions $\phi(\cdot,x)$ in standard form. Since the basic fact is standard, it may not require a reference, but in any case you might try the standard books by Schwartz (distributions), de Rham (currents), Federer (geometric measure theory).

Comment: Igor--- I think you are right, and maybe there is even an efficient way to prove it along the lines you suggest. For distributions (currents of dimension 0) it should work verbatim using the coarea formula for the integral of dp, and for positive dimensions everything should go through by appending some factors from the Jacobians of the $\phi_p$.